# Are there any good articles on the topic of how political influence differs from individual to individual?

Tags: political-theory, reference-request, political-research

I'm an industry professional writing a journal article about a certain kind of misinformation that is circulating on the internet.

My current reasoning is that public opinion shapes policy decisions and private investment. Information, whether it is accurate or not, will shape public opinion. On the internet, information is distributed based on its ability to drive engagement. Information drives engagement when it sounds interesting and plausible to a weighted majority of people. Therefore, “weight” in “weighted majority” is ultimately correlated with how much time each person spends engaging with the content on the Internet.

I'm assuming that the impact of disinformation and misinformation circulating on the internet has been studied by others. I would like to compare that to the mechanics of how public policy is influenced in the absence of misinformation. I'd also prefer to use appropriate terminology wherever possible.

Comment: I think your question have a lot of assumptions, so here is one wikipedia link that maybe can be used to remove some of the assumptions from your question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_chamber_(media)

Comment: Milton Friedman wrote on multiple occasions (including his popular audience book "Free to Choose" and in his scholarly work) that political influence is distributed more unequally than economic power, thus justifying a preference for markets over political solutions. See also this link which explains that the #1 cognitive bias of academics and political elites is overestimating how well informed average people are. https://www.forkingpaths.co/p/the-biggest-hidden-bias-in-politics